# How to hide MySQL details in Github repo

Tags: php, mysql, github

A quick question really. I'm developing an app that connects to a MySQL database. Obviously this means I have a `connect.php` file with database credentials (host, username, password).

My repo on Github is public. How do I hide this file from people viewing the repository? Obviously, I'm keen to protect any files containing security credentials.

New to Github, so apologies!

Comment: Just store placeholders in the connect.php, not real credentials

Comment: I thought of doing this. I was just wondering if there was a more automated way to achieve it. Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need to commit that file in the first place? If it is class with other method that you are using in your code, then yes place holders would work. Otherwise why commit it?

Comment: If it were me, I'd store the credentials themselves in a json file that I subsequently ignored with git-ignore. I'd have my connect.php import the credentials from credentials.json, and I'd also include a credentials-template.json file in Github, with instructions to users for filling out their own credentials and renaming the file. You could also store fake credentials, as Mark mentioned, or maybe you don't need to include connect.php at all... but assuming you want users to create their own credentials, a credentials-template file and a git-ignore of your real info is probably the way to go

Comment: Great advice everyone. At the moment I'm just committing with placeholder values localhost and the dbname is name of my software so there's no issue there. Upon release I will take @evanv advice as that seems a great solution and increasing the longevity for users!